# www.paypal.com/jp/cgi-bin/webscr? item_name encoding

Tags: encoding, paypal, payment-gateway

I am working on a site that is trying pass a japanese item name to paypal through 
this form

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
          <input name="cmd" value="_xclick" type="hidden">

          <input name="item_name" value="フォトグラフィー基礎コース" type="hidden">
          <input name="amount" value="59000" type="hidden">
          <input name="currency_code" value="JPY" type="hidden">
          <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="PHP001">
          <input name="no_note" value="0" type="hidden">
          <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="ja_JP">
          <input name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" type="hidden">
          <input class="coursepayment" name="submit" value="今すぐ購入" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" border="0" type="submit">
        </form>
```

But the Item name comes out reading: 
ãƒ•ã‚©ãƒˆã‚°ãƒ©ãƒ•ã‚£ãƒ¼åŸºç¤Žã‚³ãƒ¼ã‚¹
Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

See the documentation for the form method:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/#setting-the-character-set--charset

> **Setting the Character Set — charset**
>
> Use the charset HTML variable to specify the character set and
>   character encoding for the billing information/log-in page on the
>   PayPal website. In addition, this variable sets the same values for
>   information that you send to PayPal in your HTML button code.
>
> For example, the following INPUT tag sets the encoding to UTF-8:
>
> **<INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">**

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
      <input name="cmd" value="_xclick" type="hidden">

      <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">

      <input name="item_name" value="フォトグラフィー基礎コース" type="hidden">
      <input name="amount" value="59000" type="hidden">
      <input name="currency_code" value="JPY" type="hidden">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="PHP001">
      <input name="no_note" value="0" type="hidden">
      <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="ja_JP">
      <input name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" type="hidden">
      <input class="coursepayment" name="submit" value="今すぐ購入" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" border="0" type="submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to set the default encoding accepted by the PayPal account (which as of today is still not utf-8 until you set it that way).

Check "More Options" under https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-language-encoding